# Django - split view.py to small files

Tags: django

I have big views.py where I have class based views and `def` views.
It is possible to split it somehow to seal small files, so,  for example, in one file I have only class based views, and in other file - functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is not much special about `views.py` itself. You can implement two files for example:

```
# app/views_simpel.py

def view1(request):
    # ...
    pass

def view2(request):
    # ...
    pass
```

and another one:

```
# app/views_complex.py

def view3(request):
    # ...
    pass

def view4(request):
    # ...
    pass
```

In your `urls.py` you can then import those views, for example:

```
# app/urls.py

from django.urls import path

from app.views_simpel import view1, view2
from app.views_complex import view3, view4

urlpatterns = [
    path('view1/', view1),
    path('view2/', view2),
    path('view3/', view3),
    path('view4/', view4),
]
```

Both files can contain function-based views, class-based views, etc. In fact, the `urls.py` does not see much difference between the two, since by using `.as_view()` on a class-based view, you hand it a "dispatcher" function.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah. Not only `views`. `models` and `forms/serializers` as well.

Here's my preferred structure of an app.

```
-- app
---- models (package)
------ __init__.py
------ vehicle.py
------ trip.py

---- views (package)
------ __init__.py
------ vehicle.py
------ trip.py
```

Then you can normally import Class-based view in `urls` file like this

`from app.views.vehicle import VehicleApiView`

then customize your own routing scenario based on what's inside that view.

Same applies for `models` importing.

Comment: Are there any downsides of this way of splitting files?

Comment: @Hyperbola no there isn't

Answer (score 1):

Of course, if you want you can make different file for functions. Then you just need to import them in you `views.py` file for your classes.